# Hyphenation doesn't work and lines overflow with French Babel (Lyx)

Tags: lyx, babel

I'm using `texlive-babel-french` (on Fedora) with Lyx, and text overflows instead of having clear cuts because of hyphenation. When I change language from French to English in Document > Preferences > Language, hyphenation works correctly, but LaTeX generated text (like Abstract) is not in French anymore, so I can't use the english package.

[image: Text overflows in one of the five lines instead of having a cut because of hyphenation]

Edit: a sort of minimal example. I kept all Lyx code, because I don't know if it's of any use.

```
%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}

\makeatother
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


\makeatother

\begin{document}
Les \og visual guidelines \fg{} étaient complètes pour les usages
abordés, et la référence de l'API (qui explique chaque méthode) explicative
et claire. La documentation, quant à elle, laissait à désirer. Tout
comme d'autres documentations the rest is private information, sorry
:) but you can see how the text continues without any problem. But
I have long words like documentation documentation documentation documentation
documentationdocumentation documentation documentation documentation...
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to provide a mwe: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that I suspect that you do not use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` which properly hyphenates accentuated words.

Comment: I tried to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the Lyx preamble, but it didn't change anything. The word that overflows in my example isn't accentuated. How do I provide a minimal example with Lyx? Do I export to LaTeX ?

Comment: Also, when I erase my entire Lyx preamble and just use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Check the log-file. Is there any complain about missing hyphenation patterns. Also try to create a minimal latex export so that we can see the code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Check my edit. As for log, I don't know how to check that, but normally when I have errors Lyx complains heavily, which is not the case here.

Comment: Missing hyphenation patterns don't trigger an error, so please search the log-file. Which texsystem are you using?

Comment: Your text after being posted here is UTF-8 not latin9 (latin 9???) so I changed inputenc to `[utf8]` but apart from that your document [hyphenated as expected](http://i.stack.imgur.com/faIC5.png)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not sure what you mean, but I use pdflatex. Here's my log: http://pastebin.com/sgf8Bicm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can't make my example work: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9QoER.png. Generated from Lyx with pdflatex, I didn't try directly from the LaTeX generated.

Comment: Line 43 says, that no hyphenation patterns for french are available, and line 8 that only two languages are loaded. Did you actually install the french language in your texlive?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I installed the `texlive-babel-french` in Fedora... Did I miss a step? (sorry, I'm really a beginner in LaTeX)

Comment: I don't know what you need to do enable the patterns in fedora. If you have a texlive manager you could try to recreate the formats or to check for missing packages -- look for things with "hyphen" or "french" in its name.

Comment: I installed `texlive-collection-langfrench`, which didn't change a thing. I tried creating a new document in LaTeXila, and I didn't have a problem. The only difference is `\usepackage[francais]{babel}` (français is french for french). I used this in my Lyx preamble and it raised a "option clash for package babel" error, but it works. I'll try to specify that in Lyx.

Comment: francais or french or frenchb doesn't matter: It all maps to the same internal file. Also the babel option doesn't add hyphenation patterns. If it works now in a new document it should also work in your original setup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22923/discussion-between-hadrien01-and-ulrike-fischer).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it seems that the `\usepackage[french]{babel}` option does matter. I had hyphenation with English text, but when I changed  `Document / Settings / Language` to French, hyphens disappeared from hyphenated words. Inserting `\usepackage[french]{babel}` restored proper hyphenation on my system.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar hyphenation issue and fixed it by :

1. Turning the option `Document / Settings / Language / Language package` to None (to avoid the message "option clash for package babel").
2. Adding `\usepackage[french]{babel}` in `Document / Settings / Latex preamble`